# Bulk media upload doesn't work | Drupal

Tags: drupal, module

I'm trying for a few hours now to upload images in bulk, nothing works.

Bulk media upload seems like my saviour, but I always get this screen.

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that I needed to use Plupload 1.**, not the 2.* version.